# Perl switch/case Fails on Literal Regex String Containing Non-Capturing Group '?'

Tags: regex, perl, regex-group

I have text files containing lines like:

```
2/17/2018 400000098627 =2,000.0 $2.0994 $4,387.75
3/7/2018 1)0000006043 2,000.0 $2.0731 $4,332.78
3/26/2018 4 )0000034242 2,000.0 $2.1729 $4,541.36
4/17/2018 2)0000008516 2,000.0 $2.219 $4,637.71
```

I am matching them with `/^\s*(\S+)\s+(?:[0-9|\)| ]+)+\s+([0-9|.|,]+)\s+\$/` But I also have some files with lines in a completely different format, which I match with a different regex. When I open a file I determine which format and assign `$pat = '<regex-string>';` in a switch/case block:

```
$pat = '/^\s*(\S+)\s+(?:[0-9|\)| ]+)+\s+([0-9|.|,]+)\s+\$/'
```

But the `?` character that introduces the non-capturing group I use to match repeats after the date and before the first currency amount causes the Perl interpreter to fail to compile the script, reporting on abort:

```
syntax error at ./report-dates-amounts line 28, near "}continue "
```

If I delete the `?` character, or replace `?` with `\?` escaped character, or first assign `$q = '?'` then replace `?` with `$q` inside a `"` string assignment (ie. `$pat = "/^\s*(\S+)\s+($q:[0-9|\)| ]+)+\s+([0-9|.|,]+)\s+\$/";` ) the script compiles and runs. If I assign the regex string outside the `switch/case` block that also works OK. Perl v5.26.1 .

My code also doesn't have any `}continue` in it, which as reported in the compilation failure is probably some kind of transformation of the `switch/case` code by `Switch.pm` into something native the compiler chokes on. Is this some kind of bug in Switch.pm? It fails even when I use `given/when` in exactly the same way.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use Switch;

# Edited for demo
switch($format)
{
    # Format A eg:
    #     2/17/2018 400000098627 =2,000.0 $2.0994 $4,387.75
    #     3/7/2018 1)0000006043 2,000.0 $2.0731 $4,332.78
    #     3/26/2018 4 )0000034242 2,000.0 $2.1729 $4,541.36
    #     4/17/2018 2)0000008516 2,000.0 $2.219 $4,637.71
    #
    case /^(?:april|snow)$/i
    { # This is where the ? character breaks compilation:
        $pat = '^\s*(\S+)\s+(?:[0-9|\)| ]+)+\s+\D?(\S+)\s+\$';

      # WORKS:
      # $pat = '^\s*(\S+)\s+(' .$q. ':[0-9|\)| ]+)+\s+\D' .$q. '(\S+)\s+\$';
    }

    # Format B
    case /^(?:umberto|petro)$/i
    {
        $pat = '^(\S+)\s+.*Think 1\s+(\S+)\s+';
    }
}
```

Comment: On a little further testing it appears that a ? character appearing anywhere inside a case block, even in a # comment, causes compilation to fail. Ie. this script too:

#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use Switch;

# Edited for demo
switch($format)
{
    case /^(?:april|snow)$/i
    {
      # ? causes compilation to fail.
      $x = 1;
    }

    # Format B
    case /^(?:umberto|petro)$/i
    {
        # This comment isn't a problem.
        $y = 1;
    }
}

Comment: [Switch](http://p3rl.org/Switch) uses a source filter, which is not recommended for any serious work. Don't use it.

Comment: It fails with given/when instead of switch/case the same way.

Comment: `when` requires the regex in parentheses when it's not used as a statement modifier.

Comment: How do I parenthesize the regex in the `when` block? I tried `when (/^(?:april|snow)$/i)` but that failed with a syntax error.

Comment: Did you `use feature 'switch'` or `use v5.10`+ ? You need one of those to use `given` which was introduced in Perl v5.10.

Comment: With `when (/.../)` it works for me.

Comment: I replaced `use Switch;` with `use feature 'switch';` but compilation failed with `given is experimental` and `when is experimental`, as it did with `use feature ':5.10';` and with `use v5.10;` instead.

Comment: `given is experimental`/`when is experimental` are just warnings, not errors. If you'd want to silence them, `no warnings 'experimental::smartmatch'` (but really, consider my answer before using `switch` or `given`).

Comment: I rewrote the `switch/case` to use `for/if/elsif/else` as per Dada's answer below. It's astounding that in its 4th decade of development Perl still doesn't implement a straightforward switch/case statement block. The design is too ambitious at the expense of basic functionality.

Comment: I completely agree with your last statement @Matthew. I guess `given/when` was an attempt to remediate to that, but unfortunately ended up failing because of smartmatch, leaving us without a simple builtin `switch/case`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `Switch`. As mentionned by @choroba in the comments, `Switch` uses a source filter, which leads to mysterious and hard to debug errors, as you constated.

The module's documentation itself says:

> In general, use given/when instead. It were introduced in perl 5.10.0. Perl 5.10.0 was released in 2007.

However, `given/when` is not necessarily a good option as it is experimental and likely to change in the future (it seems that this feature was [almost removed](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2017/12/beware-of-the-removal-of-when-in-perl-v5-28/) from Perl v5.28; so you definitely don't want to start using it now if you can avoid it). A good alternative is to use `for`:

```
for ($format) {
    if (/^(?:april|snow)$/i) {
       ...
    } 
    elsif (/^(?:umberto|petro)$/i) {
       ...
    }
}
```

It might look weird a first, but once you get used to it, it's actually reasonable in my opinion. Or, of course, you can use none of this options and just do:

```
sub pattern_from_format {
    my $format = shift;

    if ($format =~ /^(?:april|snow)$/i) {
       return qr/^\s*(\S+)\s+(?:[0-9|\)| ]+)+\s+\D?(\S+)\s+\$/;
    } 
    elsif ($format =~ /^(?:umberto|petro)$/i) {
        return qr/^(\S+)\s+.*Think 1\s+(\S+)\s+/;
    }
    # Some error handling here maybe
 }
```

---

If, for some reason, you still want to use `Switch`: use `m/.../` instead of `/.../`.

I have no idea why this bug is happening, however, the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Switch#LIMITATIONS) says:

> Also, the presence of regexes specified with raw ?...? delimiters may cause mysterious errors. The workaround is to use m?...? instead.

Which I misread at first, and therefore tried to use `m/../` instead of `/../`, which fixed the issue.

Comment: A `for/if/elsif/else` block worked. It's not too weird. Though `for($format)` simply populating `$_` seems weird, no looping. Wouldn't just `$_ = $format` (or otherwise assigning $_, perhaps implicitly with some other function) before the `if/elsif/else` blocks work the same?

Comment: `for` does a bit more, as within the for, `$_` is an alias for `$format`:  `perl -E '$x=5;for($x){$_=2};say $x'` prints `2` whereas `perl -E '$x=5;{$_=$x;$_=2};say $x'` prints `2`. In that case though, it doesn't change anything. I tend to dislike statements like `$_ = $format`, but I'm not really sure why.

Comment: Thank you for all of the clarity. FWIW I'd bet that if all the programmer-years spent complaining were instead spent implementing a more basic `switch/case` then we'd have one :).

Comment: @Matthew See [Switch::Plain](https://metacpan.org/pod/Switch::Plain) for one way a more basic switch/case might look.

Comment: @Matthew I agree the situation is unfortunate, but the reality is that everyone has different ideas for what "basic" means in a language without strict typing, and what functionality they want, and that's how we got into the smartmatch mess to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Another option instead of an `if`/`elsif` chain would be to loop over a hash which maps your regular expressions to the values which should be assigned to `$pat`:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

my %switch = (
  '^(?:april|snow)$'    => '^\s*(\S+)\s+(?:[0-9|\)| ]+)+\s+\D?(\S+)\s+\$',
  '^(?:umberto|petro)$' => '^(\S+)\s+.*Think 1\s+(\S+)\s+',
);

for my $re (keys %switch) {
  if ($format =~ /$re/i) {
    $pat = $switch{$re};
    last;
  }
}
```

For a more general case (i.e., if you're doing more than just assigning a string to a scalar) you could use the same general technique, but use coderefs as the values of your hash, thus allowing it to execute an arbitrary `sub` based on the match.

This approach can cover a pretty wide range of the functionality usually associated with `switch`/`case` constructs, but note that, because the conditions are pulled from the keys of a hash, they'll be evaluated in a random order.  If you have data which could match more than one condition, you'll need to take extra precautions to handle that, such as having a parallel array with the conditions in the proper order or using [Tie::IxHash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::IxHash) instead of a regular hash.

Comment: Well, actually for each format the code must do more than just assign a regex to `$pat` , but I redacted that for posting this Question. I could take your suggestion and set `%switch` values to the `sub`s to call against a `$format` match, the Command Pattern.